# How to Communicate between JavaScript and Native Client modules

Tags: javascript, c++, google-nativeclient

I know there is one way Messaging System (in that JS sends some Message and c++ code handles that message). Apart from messaging system is there any other way by which JS can communicate with Native Client modules?

Say for example click start in JS calls m_client->start function of Native Client modules. click stop in JS calls m_client->stop function of Native Client modules.

Answer (score 1):

No, the messaging API (i.e. PostMessage) is the only direct way that JavaScript and a NaCl module can communicate directly.

You can implement something similar to what you've described like this:

```
// JavaScript
startButtonEl.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  naclModuleEl.postMessage('start');
}, false);
```

Of course, this will send a message to NaCl asynchronously. There is a new API in development that will allow synchronous communication with a NaCl module:

```
// JavaScript
startButtonEl.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var response = naclModuleEl.postMessageAndAwaitResponse('start');
  // do something with the response
}, false);
```

But this is not currently available in Chrome Stable (it landed in Chrome recently, see the bug here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=367896)